# I need function definitions that have the following OCaml types

Tags: types, ocaml, function-definition

I'm studing ocaml and I cannot figure out functions of these types. thanks.

```
1- string option list -> int -> string * string list

2- ('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> ('a -> 'b) * 'b

3- 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b list)
```

Comment: You'll need to show a bit of effort, we're not just going to do your homework for you. Can you show us what you've tried, and/or what your reasoning is, and point to some specific problems you have in figuring it out? Also, see [ask] and [an open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Also, the type signature of the function is not an expression of what the function should do. What is expected here is completely unclear.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne there is no need to be specific function, it's enough to get these types.

Comment: @glennsl yea, you are right but i'm new. if i'm looking like in here just to take hw result, sorry about that. I spent some time about this question and i figure out it's waste of time, i think. because as Richard-Degenne said, there is no information about the functions. if the question asks like "write bla bla function and get these types", i think i'll be able to do that but now i cannot figure out. If you gave me hint like "if you do this function, maybe you can get this types " that would be enough for me. thanks.

Comment: Did you read the open letter? I don't know what your teacher intends for you to learn from this, but it's very unlikely they've done this just to waste your time. Without context, and taken at face value, I'd say this is likely supposed to teach you to read types, and that given what you've learned before it should be fairly trivial to come up with an implementation that matches these types. The specifics of the implementation is probably not important, it just needs to pass the compiler using the type signatures above. Can you explain to me in your own words what the types mean?

Comment: such as string, integer... type of varible i could say?

Comment: Like *a function that takes two arguments, a tuple of a string and a list of strings, and an optional boolean, then returns a list of ints"

Comment: first one, a function takes two arguments, string list and integer then returns a tuple of string and string list.

Comment: That's almost right. The first argument type is off. If you can edit your question, do the same for each of them, and add some thoughts on how you think the argument types and return type may relate to each other, we may be able to help you connect the last few dots.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear about what the functions should actually do.

However, in order to put you on the right way, you can take a look at [type annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005176/ocaml-explicit-type-signatures). They allow you to add explicit types to fucntion parameters.

For example could look like:

```
let my_function (a : string option list) (b : int) : string * string list = ("", []);;
```

I simply don't see how such an exercise can be useful.

Comment: I assume there's an extra condition that you should use the arguments to produce the return value. Or if not, you'd have to do that for the seconds case anyway. I think this exercise is useful in teaching how to read and understand types. If the exercise had included a description of the implementation, the focus would be on the implementing it according to the description, rather than on the types.

Comment: Also, the first task of an exercise is often relatively trivial, to "set the stage"  and hint at the pattern you need to follow to solve the rest. It should be relatively obvious and easy to complete, while 2 and 3 here include type variables and higher order functions, requiring a significantly deeper understanding.

Comment: As I said, the question is completely unclear. My answer is based on is actually mentioned in the question. If the OP cares to add more context, I'll be happy to edit my answer accordingly.