# Define (without assigning) variable of custom type

Tags: types, ocaml, ml

I have the following two custom types defined:

```
type noeud = Lettre of (char * bool * arbre_lex)
and arbre_lex = noeud list
```

I can easily create an `arbre_lex` that contains **1** `noeud` element:

```
# let a = [ Lettre ('c', true, []) ];;
val a : noeud list = [Lettre ('c', true, [])]
```

> **Now how can I create an `arbre_lex` custom type that consists of 0 `noeud` elements?**

This just creates an empty list, but it is not of type `arbre_lex`...

```
# let b = [];;
val b : 'a list = []
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005176/ocaml-explicit-type-signatures) does not seem to work:

```
# let c : arbre_lex = [];;
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: You last expression prints `val c : arbre_lex = []` over here (typing your code in a fresh toplevel). Maybe the source of the error is elsewher?

Comment: Thank you... It is really strange, I tried it now several more times and now it worked.. strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I don't know what happended, but I somehow did something wrong. The correct way really is:

```
# let d : arbre_lex = [];;
val d : arbre_lex = []
```